# SQL Select UserIds with a login on two different days

Tags: sql

it's kind of embarrassing, it sounds pretty easy what i want, but i just dont get a solution for it (And i didnt even find a meaningful title, so sorry if it doesnt fit my problem)

imagine my two tables in which i store all the user-infos and the sessions a user had with my system:

```
table.users (UID, RegisteredAt, gender, locale, ...)
table.sessions (SID, UserId, LoginDate, ...)
```

what i want is a list of unique user id's which had at least one session yesterday AND today (eg 2013-08-26 and 2013-08-27). The thing is, a user can have more than one session per day and i dont want multiple userid's in my results. i tried lots of things but i think i'm just not expert enough to get it done.

My Problem is to understand how i can select a userid after comparing two rows according to userid and date_yesterday and date_today. So i'm curious which solution you experts have for that.

I hope the description is clear enough. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: elaborate the schema of your tables.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use EXISTS as follows (each subquery ensures there is a login for one day):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Users u
WHERE   EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    sessions s 
            WHERE   s.UserID = u.UID 
            AND     s.LoginDate >= '20130826' 
            AND     s.LoginDate < '20130827'
        )
AND     EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    sessions s 
            WHERE   s.UserID = u.UID 
            AND     s.LoginDate >= '20130827' 
            AND     s.LoginDate < '20130828'
        );
```

Or you could use `GROUP BY`/`HAVING`, although the exact solution will be DBMS specific (you will need to strip Time from date LoginDate)

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    Users u
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  s.UserID
            FROM    Sessions s
            WHERE   s.LoginDate >= '20130826'
            AND     s.LoginDate < '20130828'
            GROUP BY s.UserID
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(s.LoginDate AS DATE)) = 2 -- 2 DISTINCT LOGIN DATES
        ) s
            ON s.UserID = u.UID;
```

Depending on your DBMS you may have to replace `CAST(s.LoginDate AS DATE)` with something similar.